I want to convert long url to short url in last having ... how to do that
I want to convert long url to short in last having ... dots. For example this url
This is long url
text
Now, Short url
text
The code available long url to short url in above link. I am trying hard work for this. But cannot possible to make the url. I don't want to any API for url shortner. Just, using javascript.

im dont get the question. where you want to do that? on frontend? on back-end? URL for what? for pages on current website or for 3rd party one?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I assume you want to shorten the url only when displayed, not as a href value. You can do it using the following function:
// function ensuring that return value won't be longer than max, including ellipsis (...)
function shorten(text, max = 30) {
    return (text && text.length > max) ? (text.substring(0, max - 3) + "...") : url;
}

Here is a way to test shorten()
const url = "https://mozodeals.com/threads/iqoo-12-5g-worlds-fastest-processor-snapdragon%C2%AE-8-gen-3-12gb-ram-and-256gb-rom.19/";

function createLink(url) {
    document.write(`<a href=${url}>${shorten(url, 20)}</a>`);
}

createLink(url);

I hope that is what you were looking for
